# Why do we always prove cryptographic protocols via completeness and soundness?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, terminology

Most of the proofs that I have seen for cryptographic protocol include completeness and soundness.

- Why do we always prove completeness and soundness?
- Why do we not also see other propertes such as "validity", "consistency", "integrity"?

Comment: To clarify your question: Rather than write "most of the proofs I have seen for cryptographic protocol..." maybe write "the proofs I have seen for <<examples of cryptographic protocols where you have seen them>>..."

Comment: Perhaps we've looked at different proofs, which is why most of the proofs I have seen don't include completeness and soundness. Nonetheless, let me try to advise upon why completeness and soundness are useful. Soundness says that something is valid (thus, I can't prove something that isn't valid). Completeness says that everything valid can be shown (thus, nothing is considered invalid when it isn't).